# How to make a draggable element stay at the new position when dropped (HTML5 not jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-draggable

I have just learned the basics of HTML5 draggable and droppable API. I do not know how to retain the dragged position at its dropped position. On dropping it changes its position.

Here is the basic HTML (relevant elements only):

```js
onDragStart = function(ev) {
  //...
}

drop_handler = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById("id1"));
}

dragover_handler = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
}
```

```html
<div id="id1" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" style="border:2px solid green; cursor:pointer;width:100px;height:50px;">Dragged Div</div>


<div id="id2" style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:200px;border:2px solid red; cursor:pointer;width:200px;height:200px;" ondrop="drop_handler(event)" ondragover="dragover_handler(event)">Drop Div
</div>
```

I want the dragged element to remain at its final position where it it is dropped. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: You should avoid putting so many things in `style` tags, and use a css class instead

Comment: If you want the element to appear exactly where it was dropped, you'll need to work with absolute or relative positioning within the drop element. It's changing its position because it's still `position: static` (the default) and that is the normal flow of the browser... the div is just going underneath the text content that is already there. If you still need help with this I can write up a proper answer a bit later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, `<div id="id1" ...>` still has the default positioning which is `static`. Once you append it to the dropDiv, it assumes normal document flow behavior. Because it's a block element, it goes underneath the text that is already there and fills the width of the block.

If you want it to stay exactly where it is when you drop it, you need to give it `position: absolute` and take into account how the mouse moved while dragging it on the screen. In the `dragStart` event, we capture the original coordinates of the dragDiv and account for where the mouse was inside relative to the top-left corner. When we drop the dragDiv into the dropDiv, we set the absolute positioning and account for how much the mouse moved during the drag.

Since dragDiv is now a child of dropDiv, we need our new top and left values to be relative to dropDiv's coordinates rather than the entire screen, so we subtract out dropDiv's top and left values. Note well that some of these methods may not take into account the borders around the elements which may make it look like it's a pixel or two off -- to fix that you can either subtract a one or two pixels in the calculation or give them `box-sizing: border-box`.

```js
let offsetX;
let offsetY;

onDragStart = function(ev) {
  const rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();

  offsetX = ev.clientX - rect.x;
  offsetY = ev.clientY - rect.y;
};

drop_handler = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  const left = parseInt(id2.style.left);
  const top = parseInt(id2.style.top);

  id1.style.position = 'absolute';
  id1.style.left = ev.clientX - left - offsetX + 'px';
  id1.style.top = ev.clientY - top - offsetY + 'px';
  id2.appendChild(document.getElementById("id1"));
};

dragover_handler = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
};
```

```html
<div id="id1" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" style="border:2px solid green; cursor:pointer;width:100px;height:50px;">Dragged Div</div>


<div id="id2" style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:50px;border:2px solid red; cursor:pointer;width:200px;height:200px;" ondrop="drop_handler(event)" ondragover="dragover_handler(event)">Drop Div
</div>
```